# Stretch an element to fill the rest of it's container while pushing the following elements to wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout where a certain kind of element would stretch to the end of it's container and "push" the rest of the elements to wrap. Here is an image of what the end result would look like:

[image]

The blue boxes and the green container all have a defined width but the purple boxes do not. The html would simply be something like this:

```css
.green_container{
  padding:10px;
  width:350px;
  border:1px solid green;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.blue_box{
  min-width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  margin:5px;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.purple_box{
  min-width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid purple;
   margin:5px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="green_container">
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="purple_box"></div>
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="purple_box"></div>
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="blue_box"></div>
   <div class="purple_box"></div>
</div>
```

The use of flex is not essential, so long as the elements are able to wrap naturally.
Is achieving this in CSS possible? The blue boxes are interactive and can be resized and moved (handled in javascript) on the fly by users, so recalculating the width of ALL boxes in the container or injecting additional elements are things I am trying to avoid. Ideally the purple box would naturally push the remaining content down.

Comment: why not use `float: right`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I'm probably cheating. Close as I can get...

The toughest rule here is:

> Ideally the purple box would naturally push the remaining content down.

This means there can be any number and width of blue boxes on a virtual row and the purple box for that virtual row has to pick up the slack. This creates a problem when there's enough space left on a virtual row to add another blue box because the next blue box wants to go up one row with a `flex: 1` based solution.

The visual trickery around `min-width: 100%` for the purple boxes allows the purple box to pick up the slack by really just taking over the whole row. Problem is it leaves an implicit gap when blue boxes resize enough to push out other blue boxes allowed on that row. Maybe there's another rule that limits the `max-width` of the blue boxes so all blue boxes on a row must stay on that row?

I just noticed I've done nothing to allow for the other tricky requirement:

> The blue boxes are interactive and can be resized and **moved** on the fly by users

This solution handles `resize` but not `draggable`...

```css
.green_container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.blue_box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor: move;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

.purple_box {
  height: 50px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 0;
  background-color: purple;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="green_container">
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="purple_box"></div>
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="purple_box"></div>
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="blue_box" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class="purple_box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty clever solution but unfortunately doesn't quite work. I should have mentioned that the "position" of the elements (in respect to each other) is important, with the purple boxes acting as line breaks, without being one. Visually this works great, but when you add the drag & drop it not longer works. I appreciate the effort however!

Comment: @frboud Hehe, thanks, I gave it a shot ;) If you can update your question with the JavaScript for drag and drop, I'll test out some "line break" type functionality. Can there ever be any rows with no blue boxes and just a full width purple box? Can the green box be expanded to create a new row with a moved blue box?

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS grid instead of flexbox might be a good choice. You can use e.g. `grid-column: 3 / -1;` for the first purple box and `2 / -1` for the second purple box and so on. CSS grid columns (and rows for that matter) always count in ascending order from left to right (or top to bottom), starting at 1, and in descending order from right to left (or bottom to top), starting at -1.

I know, judging by [caniuse.com - flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and [caniuse.com - grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), the support for grid is a bit worse but it might be worth this tradeoff.

Comment: Unfortunately the blue box are resizable, so not always equal.

Comment: Oh sry, did I miss that or did you add that requirement afterwards?